# Permission denied when setting the MAC address

Tags: networking, root

I'm trying to set my mac address for my other computer on a newly installed Ubuntu with a brand new hard drive. While doing this I got “permission denied” from `SIOCSIFFLAGS`.

My question is how can I get to the root of Ubuntu to get total control of my machine?

Comment: Hi,welcome to askubuntu. Just for clarification you did start the command with `sudo` EG instead of `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` for example it should be `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`  It would also be more helpful if you added the commands you have used to your question to receive better help.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a shell command to perform a task that requires system administrator permission, you need to put `sudo` in front of it. `sudo` stands for “do as super user”. You will be prompted for your password (if you run several commands in quick succession, you will only get a password prompt the first time), and you must be authorized to run command as administrator (which is the case for the initial user created during an Ubuntu installation).

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 hwaddr 01:23:45:67:89:ab
```

See [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for more information.

If adding `sudo` isn't enough, edit your question to be more precise. Copy-paste the command(s) that you ran and the error messages.